# Make The Swipe gesture Animated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i have swipe gesture that switch between tab bars when I swipe in the screen right or left its change the tab bar im in it
How would I make it so it looks like it is sliding to the right or left tab bar rather than just instantly changing the tab bar

```
class SwipeGesture: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeLeft))
        left.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(left)

        let right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRight))
        right.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(right)

    }

    @objc func swipeLeft() {
        let total = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers!.count - 1
        tabBarController!.selectedIndex = min(total, tabBarController!.selectedIndex + 1)

    }

    @objc func swipeRight() {
        tabBarController!.selectedIndex = max(0, tabBarController!.selectedIndex - 1)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect using this [pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/XLPagerTabStrip)

If you want to build it from scratch, you need to subclass `containerView`. Then put the view controllers (childVCs) inside a `scrollView` (scrolls only in horizontal direction).

Comment: if i cant do that then i need to rebuild my app from scratch i don't want no pods sorry i need code i know how to use it but i need code